# Incredible Night Wave Light System

Tags: led

I want to have a nice night-light-waves projector at home.

Not a simple and primitive toy for children as
[image]

But a super-level beautiful dynamic waves system, as in the movie ["Blade Runner 2049"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856101/):
[image]

Any ideas?)

Comment: This might fall into the DIY category, rather than hardware recommendations, but consider that the image you provide is likely created by light traveling through a liquid. One would use water, mineral oil, vegetable oil, just about any transparent fluid. Modifying an existing device to send the illumination through the medium might be challenging, but that's the fun of DIY.

Comment: @fred_dot_u , But it seems that DIY is not for shopping recommendations

Comment: Then you'll have to be more specific with your requirements.